# Search in custom admin grid redirects to dashboard

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, grid

I have created a custom module to display some data in admin grid, but when I am trying to search it is redirecting me to admin dashboard. 
Below is my grid.php code

```
class My_Custom_Block_Adminhtml_Business_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('custom_grid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('desc');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}

/**
 * Prepare collection for grid
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
 */
protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getSingleton('custom/business')->getCollection();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

/**
 * Prepare columns for grid
 */
protected function _prepareColumns() {
    $this->addColumn('id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('custom')->__('ID'),
        'align' => 'right',
        'width' => '50px',
        'index' => 'id',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('custom')->__('Name'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'index' => 'extension_name',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('address', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('custom')->__('Address'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'index' => 'address',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('phone', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('custom')->__('Phone'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'index' => 'phone',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('email', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('custom')->__('Email'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'index' => 'email',
    ));

    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('custom')->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('custom')->__('XML'));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

/**
 * Generate grid data in csv
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCsv() {
    $csv = '';
    $this->_isExport = true;
    $this->_prepareGrid();

    $this->_afterLoadCollection();

    $data = array();
    foreach ($this->_columns as $column) {
        if (!$column->getIsSystem()) {
            $data[] = '"' . $column->getExportHeader() . '"';
        }
    }
    $csv.= implode(',', $data) . "\n";

    foreach ($this->getCollection() as $item) {
        $data = array();
        foreach ($this->_columns as $column) {
            if (!$column->getIsSystem()) {
                $data[] = '"' . str_replace(array('"', '\\'), array('""', '\\\\'), $column->getRowFieldExport($item)) . '"';
            }
        }
        $csv.= implode(',', $data) . "\n";
    }

    if ($this->getCountTotals()) {
        $data = array();
        foreach ($this->_columns as $column) {
            if (!$column->getIsSystem()) {
                $data[] = '"' . str_replace(array('"', '\\'), array('""', '\\\\'), $column->getRowFieldExport($this->getTotals())) . '"';
            }
        }
        $csv.= implode(',', $data) . "\n";
    }

    return $csv;
}

/**
 * Generate xml for grid data
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getXml() {
    $this->_isExport = true;
    $this->_prepareGrid();

    $this->_afterLoadCollection();
    $indexes = array();
    foreach ($this->_columns as $column) {
        if (!$column->getIsSystem()) {
            $indexes[] = $column->getIndex();
        }
    }
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    $xml.= '<cards>';
    foreach ($this->getCollection() as $item) {
        $xml.= $item->toXml($indexes);
    }
    if ($this->getCountTotals()) {
        $xml.= $this->getTotals()->toXml($indexes);
    }
    $xml.= '</cards>';
    return $xml;
}

/**
 * Grid url
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getGridUrl() {
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current' => true));
}
```

}

I have tried both ways by overidding

```
protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
```

my custom grid.php and also using the parent method. But nothing works.
And also I am getting all the data from a single table.

Please help me out in finding some solution and what is the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You either don't have `gridAction()` method in your controller or `<.._grid>` habdle in your layout xml. If you are redirected to dasboard also when you click on column header to reorder by this column - it is definitely your case.

Comment: @Zyava I have grid action like <adminhtml_business_grid>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
            <block type="custom/adminhtml_business_grid" name="admin.business.grid"/>
        </block>
    </adminhtml_business_grid>

Comment: And I have added the gridAction() {$this->loadLayout(); $this->renderLayout();} but it is showing me please wait pop-up box and just hanged there only.

Comment: Check with firebug what is going on when you clicked on search button and see ajax spinner. Without code it is hard to understand what you did wrong.

Comment: @AnshuMishra are you sure that the layout handle should be `<adminhtml_business_grid>` and not `<custom_adminhtml_business_grid>`? I mean, what does the URL of your grid look like? `/admin/business/index` or `business/adminhtml_business/index`?

Comment: @Marius Url is /admin/business/index

Comment: I don't know what was wrong but know I have changed by grid action : gridAction() {$this->loadLayout(false); $this->renderLayout();} and everything is working fine.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what is the difference between loadLayout() and loadLayout(false) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed by grid action as follows

```
gridAction() {
    $this->loadLayout(false); 
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

When using ajax for grid refresh (`$grid->setUseAjax(true)`), it's necessary to define (override) `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::getGridUrl()` to return the proper AJAX content endpoint; this URL will be inserted into the JS. You have done this and have indicated "current module, current controller, `grid` action" as the arguments.

The next step is to define the indicated controller action to return *just* the grid content. You can do this a couple of ways: with layout and without. It's more conventional to use layout as it provides flexibility and ensures certain layout-based events are dispatched. Typically you can define a layout update handle with just the grid block declared as an output block. You have done this as well.

However, the controller action which handles the AJAX request needs to *not* invoke the typical full adminhtml layout, namely the `<default>` handle. By calling `loadLayout(false)`, the default handle is omitted. For more information, see [`Mage_Core_Controller_Action::loadLayout()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L249):

```
public function loadLayout($handles = null, $generateBlocks = true, $generateXml = true)
{
    // if handles were specified in arguments load them first
    if (false!==$handles && ''!==$handles) {
        $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle($handles ? $handles : 'default');
    }
    // ... etc. ...
}
```